# Проблемы при сборке Maven проекта в IntellijIDea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

В intelijiIdea я создал простой java проект на Maven. В папке main -> java создал класс Main, где прописал метод System.out.println("Hello, World!").
На сколько мне известно при компиляции обычно в Maven в консоль кроме самого результата выводится вот такой блок(всего лишь пример):

```java
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------< com.project.maven:maven.3.6.2 >--------------------
[INFO] Building maven.3.6.2 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ maven.3.6.2 ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\Артур\maven362\target
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.703 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-09-12T13:14:54+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Дело в том, что у меня кроме результата Hello, World ничего подобного не выводится.

Почему не происходит сборки проекта?

Comment: Какой коммандой собирали проект? `mvn install` должен создать Jar файл, если вы хотите именно его. Если вы просто нажали на молоточек, то проект сбилдил intellij через maven, избавив вас от лишних выводов в консоль.

Comment: то есть это абсолютно нормально, то что в консоль ИДЕи выдался только результат без лишнего текста? Я просто нажал на Run.

Comment: Да. Intellij оборачивает maven и использует его для сборки, по сути пропукая все INFO логи. Если хотите, можете запускать Maven напрямую через консоль и вы увидите эти же логи. Если же у вас будут предупреждения или ошибки (WARNING/ERROR), то intellij  вас предупредит. Она отсекает только лишний шум, оставляя полезную информацию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intellij оборачивает maven и использует его для сборки, по сути пропуcкая все INFO логи. Если хотите, можете запускать Maven напрямую через консоль и вы увидите эти же логи. Если же у вас будут предупреждения или ошибки (WARNING/ERROR), то intellij вас предупредит. Она отсекает только лишний шум, оставляя полезную информацию. Так что вывод выше показанных блоков текста не обязателен в данной среде разработки.